# Symfony 2: Form Permissions Authorization Strategy

Tags: symfony, access-control

I have a Symfony application with five different entities (what they are doesn't really matter).

For each of these entities, a registered user must either have NONE, READ, EDIT, DELETE permissions. The sticky part for me to grasp is that each user can have different permissions for each entity; User A can edit Entity A, but can only view Entity B, etc.

Now on each user's options page, an admin should be able to see his permissions for each form. Radio buttons should be displayed with the four options for each form. Something like:

```
Entity A:  O NONE    O READ    X EDIT    O DELETE
Entity B:  O NONE    X READ    O EDIT    O DELETE
...
```

I know my choices are basically between creating some type of Voter system or an Access Control List.

At first I just started by listing all of the roles currently in the system within my UserType:

```
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->roles,
            'choices_as_values' => true,
            'label' => 'Roles',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'mapped' => true,
        ))
    ;
```

but I'm feeling like this isn't going to be very effective in the long run. And either way, this also displays other system roles that have nothing to do with access control to specific entities (such as ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, etc.)

I'm not looking for a complete solution or anything like that, I'm just having a really hard time getting started and seeing the big picture on how to make this happen. (And yes, I am aware of the Symfony documentation...sometimes that stuff just doesn't make a ton of sense at first).

**PROGRESS UPDATE**

I decided on **Access Control List**.

First, when a new entity is created, I use the standard ACL creation strategy as mentioned in the Symfony Documentation:

```
public function postAvrequestAction(Request $request){
        $entity = new AvRequest();

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new AvRequestType(), $entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
            $serialized = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');


            // creating the ACL
            $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
            $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($entity);
            $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

            // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
            $tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
            $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();

            //$tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            foreach($users as $user){
              $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

              // grant owner access based on owner's overall permissions for this type of entity
              $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, 0);
              $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
            }

            return new Response($serialized, 201);
        }

        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'errors' => $this->getFormErrors($form)
        ));
    }
```

Next, I created a service with all of the necessary dependencies to update a user's permissions for each entity:

```
#services.yml
services:
    user_service:
      class: AppBundle\Resources\Services\UserService
      arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @service_container, @security.authorization_checker, @security.acl.provider ]
```

The service has the function:

```
/**
 * ACLs grant user permission on every instance of each entity.
 * In order to edit permissions across all of these entites for each user,
 * first iterate over all entities. 
 * For each entity, update the permission for the specified user.
 *
 * @param  \AppBundle\Entity\User $user  The user object whose permissions should be updated
 * @param String $entity  The entity whose permissions should be updated (e.g. 'AppBundle:AvRequest')
 * @param int $permission  The bitmask value of the permission level (e.g. MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW (=4))
 * 
 * @return null
 */
  public function editPermission(User $user, $entity, $permission){
    $allEntities = $this->em->getRepository($entity)->findAll();

    foreach($allEntities as $oneEntity){
      // locate the ACL
      $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($oneEntity);
      $acl = $this->aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);

      // update user access
      $objectAces = $acl->getObjectAces();
      foreach($objectAces as $i => $ace) {
          $acl->updateObjectAce($i, $permission); 
      }
    }
  }
```

This function goes through every instance of the entity and gives it the same permission level for the specified user.

**The next step that I haven't quite figured out yet is** setting a master permission level for a user on an entity as described up top with my radio buttons. I need to be able to go to the user's profile page, see a radio list of the user's permissions for each entity type, submit the radio button value and then run the editPermission() function on save.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Access Control Lists](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html). It is easy to set permission by user or group of users.

Add access level by user:

```
$builder = new MaskBuilder();
$builder
    ->add('view')
    ->add('edit')
    ->add('delete')
    ->add('undelete')
;
$mask = $builder->get(); // int(29)

$identity = new UserSecurityIdentity('johannes', 'AppBundle\Entity\User');
$acl->insertObjectAce($identity, $mask);
```

Specify min access level by entity:

```
public function addCommentAction(Post $post)
{
    $comment = new Comment();

    // ... setup $form, and submit data

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // creating the ACL
        $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($comment);
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

        // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
        $tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
        $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

        // grant owner access
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
        $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }
}
public function editCommentAction(Comment $comment)
{
    $authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

    // check for edit access
    if (false === $authorizationChecker->isGranted('EDIT', $comment)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    // ... retrieve actual comment object, and do your editing here
}
```

Comment: Yes I do remember seeing this. So correct me if I'm wrong: every instance of every entity will be logged into the ACL; it's not just an over-arching rule for an entire entity class? And then in the MaskBuilder example, I see the permissions being set for a user but how does that specify permissions for a specific entity?

Comment: @Ravioli87 Did you read the Cookbook post about that? It is like a tutorial and answer all your questions you are asking for. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Comment: @Ravioli87 Dependending on your need, you could also create a voter to do that : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Comment: Yes. The cookbook got me about 30% of the way there. My updated question shows what I've been able to complete so far.